# requestAnimationFrame not working when callback not utilised directly

Tags: javascript, timer, requestanimationframe

I am trying to impl a timer that makes use of `requestAnimationFrame` to keep the timer on even while user has moved onto other tabs and windows.

I am facing an issue where unless I directly make use of the `callback` from the the `requestAnimationFrame` WebAPI it just doesn't work! I am not really sure where I went wrong in understanding this Web API.

**Working Impl**

```js
    var count = 0;

    var updateTimer = function (timestamp) {
        count = timestamp;

        let s = Math.floor((count / 1000) % 60);
        let m = Math.floor((count / 60000) % 60);
        let h = Math.floor(count / 3600000);

        let formattedHours = h < 10 ? "0" + h.toString() : h;
        let formattedMinutes = m < 10 ? "0" + m.toString() : m;
        let formattedSeconds = s < 10 ? "0" + s.toString() : s;

        timer.textContent = formattedHours + ":" + formattedMinutes + ":" + formattedSeconds;

        prevTimestamp = timestamp;

        rAF_ID = requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);
    }
```

In the picture below you can see the log when I hit the "Finish" button. This is after I have moved away from the tab for a couple of seconds.
[image]

**Non-Working Impl**

```js
    var milliseconds = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var hours = 0;

    let rAF_ID;
    var prevTimestamp = 0;

    var updateTimer = function (timestamp) {
        // Calculate the elapsed time between calls i.e., since previous frame in milliseconds
        var elapsedTime = timestamp - prevTimestamp;

        // Here we needed an additional variable called "milliseconds" to capture the timer progress because "timestamp" typically represents the number 
        // of milliseconds elapsed since the page started loading or since a specific point in time (e.g., the beginning of the page's execution).
        milliseconds += elapsedTime;

        if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
            milliseconds = 0;
            seconds++;
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                if (minutes >= 60) {
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours++;
                    if (hours >= 24) {
                        hours = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // console.log(timestamp, milliseconds, seconds, elapsedTime);

        let formattedHours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours.toString() : hours;
        let formattedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes.toString() : minutes;
        let formattedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds.toString() : seconds;

        timer.textContent = formattedHours + ":" + formattedMinutes + ":" + formattedSeconds;

        prevTimestamp = timestamp;

        rAF_ID = requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);
    }
```

In the picture below you can see the difference in the log and the timer.
[image]

I can't really work with the `timestamp` alone because it is always returning milliseconds since the page loading and that is no good, since after pausing the timer and restarting doesn't start the timer where I left.

This is how my `startTimer` looks like:

```js
    async function startTimer() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            if (milliseconds === 0 && seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0) {
                timer.textContent = "00:00:00"
                counter.textContent = "00:00:00"
            }

            isRunning = true;
            startTimestamps.push(new Date().getTime());

            function sleep(ms) {
                return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
            }
            await sleep(1000);

            rAF_ID = requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);

            updateCounter();
            logActivity();
        }
    }
```

You can have a look at a working version that has the problem of stopping when the tab is out of focus!
https://iamsmkr.github.io/seesaw/